# avoiding creation of temporary or permanent tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, temp-tables

I want to manipulate with a table, but the only solution I found so far is to create some tables first and join them together to the desired results.

I'm trying to avoid creating tables and dropping them at the end of my MySQL query which btw, I'm running on phpmyadmin page.

Here is the data: I have one table containing user_id, columnA_unixtime, columnB_unixtime -- meaning that for each user there are two unix_time stored in the database for two different events.

```
user_id     eventA_join     eventB_join
1           1321652009      1321652009
2           0               1321652257
3           0               1321668650
4           1321669261      0
```

what I want to have is a table showing how many users joined the two events for each day. Something like this (just a sample)

```
day       eventA    eventB
11/18/11    3       2
11/19/11    11      8
11/20/11    6       3
11/21/11    17      11
```

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
day VARCHAR(256),
eventA_count INT);

INSERT INTO table1 (day, eventA_count)
(SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('eventA_join') ) AS 'day', COUNT('user_id') AS 'eventA_count'
FROM org_table
WHERE 'eventA_join' > 0
GROUP BY day);

CREATE TABLE table2(
day VARCHAR(256),
eventB_count INT);

INSERT INTO table2 (day, eventB_count)
(SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('eventB_join') ) AS 'day', COUNT('user_id') AS 'eventB_count'
FROM org_table
WHERE 'eventB_join' > 0
GROUP BY day);


SELECT t.day, t1.eventA_count, t2.eventB_count FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT day FROM table1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT day FROM table2) t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
ON t.day = t1.day
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t.day = t2.day

DROP table2;
DROP table1;
```

As far as I tried I couldn't use table variables in phpmyadmin and neither I could use template tables because there was no way to refer to template tables multiple times (error #10327 Can't reopen temporary table) when I try to join them together.

Is there anyway I avoid creating tables but gain what I'm looking for? Any thoughts?

Edit: both tables are getting data from 'org_table' which is now corrected in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with a single query.  You just need UNION ALL:

```
select date, sum(IsEventA) as EventA, sum(isEventB) as EventB
from ((select user_id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('eventA_join') as date,
              1 as IsEventA, 0 as IsEventB
       from table1
       where eventA_join > 0
      ) union all
      (select user_id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('eventB_join') as date,
              0 as IsEventA, 1 as IsEventB
       from table1
       where eventB_join > 0
      )
     ) t
group by date
order by 1
```

Comment: Yes. This works well and shows me how to make an aggregation of two selects. Thank you @Gordon